# Background color of an element in robot framework

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Is there any way to find the following in robot  framework ?

1. Background color of an element.
2. Whether an element is clickable or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `${bgcolor}    Execute Javascript    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myElementID"),null)['background-color']`
2. Depends what "clickable" means. All elements are clickable.

Assuming you use Selenium2Library.

Comment: See I have a page , on click of some button another div is going to overlay on top of the page. Then I need to verify that I cannot click on anything in the tat page. How can do I do it ?

Comment: Click that element by Click Element keyword. See that nothing happens. Or wait until the element that covers the other element is visible and just assume the other element is not clickable anymore. Or get location of both elements by Execute Javascript and check that one element is hover the other element. The correct method depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium2Screenshots](https://robotframework-selenium2screenshots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/keywords.html#Update%20element%20style) library has a keyword named `Update Element Style` which uses jQuery to update element style. Basically the same as already mentioned, just more convenient to use.