How i can click and hold button in Robot Framework? And how to get background color of the button?
I've just started learning automation, and robot is my first framework, I'm solving some tests from letcode.in practice. But I can't solve two problems from the second test: 1) Get the background color of the button 2) Press and hold the button. I will be grateful for any help or comments.
*** Settings ***
Documentation    First robot test
Library          SeleniumLibrary
Library    .venv/Lib/site-packages/robot/libraries/XML.py


*** Variables ***
${URL}    https://letcode.in/buttons
${BROWSER}        Chrome

${hold_button}    css://#color

*** Keywords ***
Prepare for test
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Set Selenium Speed    3 seconds


*** Test Cases ***
Buttons
    Prepare for test
    Maximize Browser Window

    Click Button    id:home
    Go Back

    ${y_coord}=    Get Vertical Position    id:position
    ${x_coord}=    Get Horizontal Position    id:position
    Log    Y coordinate: ${y_coord}
    Log    X coordinate: ${x_coord}


    # ${color}=    Get Element Attribute    id:color    style.background-color
    # Log    Button color:${color}

    ${tall&fat}=    Get Element Size    id:property
    Log    Button sizes: ${tall&fat}

    Element Should Be Disabled    id:isDisabled

    # Click Button    ${hold_button}
    # Click Element   ${hold_button}    
    # Sleep    3
    

I`ve commented my last attempts, I'm a beginner, so I'm not sure if I'm good at reading documentation and searching for information on the Internet.

this code is currently working for me:
*** Settings ***
Documentation    First robot test
Library          SeleniumLibrary


*** Variables ***
${URL}            https://letcode.in/buttons
${BROWSER}        Chrome
${HOLD_BUTTON}    //button[contains(., 'Button')]

*** Test Cases ***
Buttons
    [Documentation]    Test case
    Prepare For Test
    Maximize Browser Window
    Click Button    id:home
    Go Back
    ${y_coord}=    Get Vertical Position    id:position
    ${x_coord}=    Get Horizontal Position    id:position
    Log    Y coordinate: ${y_coord}
    Log    X coordinate: ${x_coord}
    ${color}=    Get Element Attribute    id:color    style.background-color
    Log    Button color:${color}
    ${tall&fat}=    Get Element Size    id:property
    Log    Button sizes: ${tall&fat}
    Element Should Be Disabled    id:isDisabled
    # Click Element   ${HOLD_BUTTON}
    Mouse Down        ${HOLD_BUTTON}
    Wait Until Page Contains    Button has been long pressed    timeout=5s
    Mouse Up    ${HOLD_BUTTON}

*** Keywords ***
Prepare For Test
    Open Browser            ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Set Selenium Speed      1 seconds


Yes it works, thanks a lot!!! But i still cant get background color of button, the test didnt fail, but the background color at the logs is written as None

You can checkout the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38617413/17041240 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27815560/17041240. If you want to convert the value to HEX, you can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296823/how-to-get-background-color-in-hex-format-from-element-using-robot-framework. Hope this helps.
